# React code splitting and one bundle for new and one bundle for older browsers

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a new React.js project using create-react-app and was wondering is it possible to do component based code splitting, however serve two different bundles based on the browser version? So for IE11 and other older browsers that don't support a lot of ES6 features serve a version which has the needed transforms in, then for newer browsers serve another version which doesn't need as many transforms in?

Essentially I don't want newer browsers to have to serve up and the transpiled code which adds unnecessary bloat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think bloat added by ES6 to ES5 transpilation is a real problem. Usually the extra lines or polyfills for certain functions are relatively small compared to things like 3rd party libraries. If your bundle is bloated or bigger than you want then it's almost a certainty that transforms are not the main culprit, and there would be plenty of other stuff you should look at first. I'd say you're most likely looking to streamline in the wrong place.

Comment: Hopefully this tweet which sparked my reason for asking this might help explain why I'm thinking about this - https://twitter.com/jamiebuilds/status/1072180184290217985

Comment: hmm interesting. For all the projects I've worked on, both professionally and personally, I was always able to get a viably small bundle size even while transpiling everything to ES5. And in the few instances when I did need to cut down bundle size, it was always some 3rd party library that was causing the trouble. It would be interesting to see a size comparison for all kinds of code in ES5 vs. ES6, I couldn't find one.

Comment: Plus I assume the user would have to do 2 network requests, 1 to get the Javascript that determines their browser version, then another to request the right built version. I wonder the impact that'd have, if it's still be worth it. Definitely an interesting thought!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use polyfills instead of doing that?

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill